# next auth oauth callback

Tags: next.js, oauth, next-auth

Generates one time access code and calls callback URL defined in App settings case:

[image]

in this case
can i get another parameter? ex) api/auth/github/callback?code=123&test=1111

if include test parameter i want to route '/test' link

like this
how can i get another parameter and route link?

im trying to change callbacks in redirect
but it is not working...